# Trying to use seed value in generating random chars to test program. As well as convert random generated int to char

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

This is what I am trying to print with the seed value of 9999 (See image in link). The program asks user to enter int value, I already checked for errors in main class using getSeed(). In addition disregard the input file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int seed = getSeed();
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    while(inFile.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(inFile.nextLine());
        Board b = new Board(seed);
    }
}
```

[Board Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biN41.png)

When I run my program, I receive a null pointer error. Also I was wonder how I would properly convert to char.

Thank you for your insight.

```
public static int getSeed(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput;
        while(true){                                                            
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter an integer seed value greater than      0:                ");
                userInput = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
                if( userInput > 0)
                    return userInput;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid!");
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Shiven When I run my program, I receive a null pointer error. Also I was wonder how I would properly convert to char

Comment: Can you give us the source from the `getSeed()` method?

Comment: @GustavoCinque edited above. Thank you

Comment: Whats the relation between 9999 and that board? What problem is the program trying to solve? And where exactly do you get the nullpointer exception?

Comment: @Jim Did the answer provided help?

Answer (score 1):

Your board class has a couple of errors:

1. Board[][] has not been initialized hence the Nullpointer exception
2. In function resetBoard() you should have board[i][j] = randomChar and not vice versa.

3.The loops should end at 4 in order to give a 4*4 board. What you have would give a 5*5 array.

I have rewritten the class to:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by derricknyakiba on 07/10/2016.
 */
public class Board {

private char[][] board;
private boolean[][] visited;
private String word;

public  Board(int seed){
    board = new char[4][4];
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
        for( int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++ ){
            char randomChar = (char) (rand.nextInt(27) + 65);
            board[i][j] = randomChar;            }
    }
    printBoard();

}
public void printBoard(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
        for( int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++ ){
            System.out.print( board[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```